# Calculate MonthlyVolume - PIVOT SQL

Tags: sql

I am using SQL server 2008 and I have following Table with millions of rows...Here are few sample records

```
Serial_Num  ReadingDate M_Counter   Dyn_Counter
XYZ 3/15/2014   100 190
XYZ 4/18/2014   140 240
XYZ 5/18/2014   200 380
ABC 3/12/2014   45  40
ABC 4/19/2014   120 110
ABC 5/21/2014   130 155
```

This table will always have only one reading for each month and no missing months....

and I would like calculate M_Counter and Dyn_Counter values for each month, For an example XYZ -> May month calculated counter value should be 60 = 200 (05/18/2014 value) - 140 (04/18/2014 value). I would like to insert data into another table in following way.

```
CalculatedYear  CalculatedMonth Serial_Num  M_Counter_Calc  Dyn_Counter_Calc
2014    4   XYZ 40  50
2014    5   XYZ 60  140
2014    4   ABC 75  70
2014    5   ABC 10  45
```

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: This is not a PIVOT scenario. What DBMS are you using? This is a common question, you should find existing answers with a little research.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS SQL, something like this should work.   The concept is to sort the dataset based on Serial_Num and ReadingDate.  Add a sequential Row ID and store into a temp table.    Join the table onto itself such that you match up the current row with the previous row where the serial numbers still match.    If there wasn't a prior month's reading, the value will be null.  We use Isnull( x, 0) to account for this when doing the calculations.

```
declare @Temp1 table
(
RowID int,
Serial_Num varchar(3),
ReadingDate datetime,
M_Counter int,
Dyn_Counter int
)


insert into @Temp1
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Serial_Num, ReadingDate), * 
from MyTable T


select 
Year(T1.ReadingDate) As CalculatedYear, 
Month(T1.ReadingDate) as CalculatedMonth,
T1.Serial_Num, 
T1.M_Counter - ISNULL(T2.M_Counter,0) as Calculated_M_Counter, 
T1.Dyn_Counter - isnull(T2.Dyn_Counter,0) as Calculated_Dyn_Counter
from @Temp1 T1
left outer join @Temp1 T2 on T1.RowID = T2.RowID + 1 and T1.Serial_Num = T2.Serial_Num 
order by T1.Serial_Num, Year(T1.ReadingDate), Month(T1.ReadingDate)
```